# Jquery iteration not showing all column

Tags: jquery, django, python-3.x

this is my code :

```
  $('#addrowbtn1').on('click', function () {
            var cnt = $('#testTable tr th').length;
            var html = '';

            //html += '<tr class="tempcls" id="tr' + k + '">';
            var i =0;
                html += '<tr id="tr'+k+'">\n' +
                    '<td style="display: none"><input type="text" value=0></td>'+
                    '{% for x in headers %}\n' +
                    '           <td id="t' + +k+ i++ + '" align="center">\n' +
                    '           {% if x.ddlist_len  == 0 and x.type == "str" %}\n' +
                    '               <input type="text" name="f' + i + '' + k + '">\n' +
                    '           {% elif x.ddlist_len  == 0 and x.type == "num" %}\n' +
                    '               <input type="number" name="f' + i + '' + k + '">\n' +
                    '           {% else %}\n' +
                    '               {% if x.name == "Common_Name" %}\n' +
                    '                   <select class="select_d">\n' +
                    '               {% for y in x.ddlist %}\n' +
                    '                   <option value="{{y.id}}">{{ y.value }} </option>\n' +
                    '               {% endfor %}\n' +
                    '                   </select>\n' +
                    '               {% else %}\n' +
                    '                   <select>\n' +
                    '                   {% for y in x.ddlist %}\n' +
                    '                       <option value="{{y.id}}">{{ y.value }} </option>\n' +
                    '               {% endfor %}\n' +
                    '                   </select>\n' +
                    '               {% endif %}'
                    '           {% endif %}\n' +
                    '           </td>\n' +
                    '{% endfor %}\n' +
                    '</tr>'

            k++;
            //html += '</tr>';
            $('#testTable tbody').append(html);

        });
```

and this is output:
[image]

this shows only one column but I have many columns in the header object. 
I am want to add a class (show_d) to the column which name is Common_Name

Comment: I think you would have got more responses if you had posted a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt. Right now this is too much code to review and provide any help.

Comment: but it necessary for understand my problem